# Copy the output of the last command in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

`!! | pbcopy` would also run the commands again and couldn't be used with interactive commands.

This relies on the prompt always being `$` :

```
tell application "Terminal" to tell window 1 to history
do shell script "/bin/echo " & quoted form of result & ¬
    " | ruby -e 'puts $<.read.split(/^\\$ .*?$/)[-2][1..-1]'"
set the clipboard to result
```

Does anyone know any better options?

Comment: And !! not good for command with side effects

Comment: Can you add a real example of what you're trying to accomplish with this? Fill in the blanks "I want to copy the output of the last command, because the last command was ________ and I want to paste it into _______"

Comment: @DougHarris I'd just want to assign a keyboard shortcut to a general purpose script for copying the previous output. That fill in the blanks thing is insanely patronizing BTW.

Comment: You might consider it patronising, but it's often the best way to succinctly understand what a user wants.

Comment: You could make `exec script $( date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S )` your Terminal startup command to log everything to a dated log file. One unfortunate side effect is that `script` is a lousy shell (e.g. always 80 wide) in my limited testing.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using at least el Capitan you can use Cmd-shift-A to select the output of the last command and Cmd-C to copy it.
Unfortunately this doesn't work for previous versions.

---

Edited to add updates from the comments:

- this also works for other than just the latest command: first select any part of the output of any previous command manually, and then hit Cmd + Shift + A
- after trying this shortcut in iTerm, it asks to install some Shell Integrations and then this keyboard shortcut starts working in iTerm as well, see https://superuser.com/a/1242752/676978 for more details

Comment: This is great. And this also works for other than just the latest command: first select any part of the output of any previous command manually, and then hit Cmd + Shift + A.

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen when I tried this shortcut in iTerm, it asked me if I wanted to install some Shell Integrations and when I did that, this keyboard shortcut started working in iTerm as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Original answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806598/copying-last-bash-command-into-clipboard#comment71039990_24807390)

> If you're on OSX, a spiffy alias I'd recommend for this is
>
> alias copyLastCmd="fc -ln -1 | pbcopy".
>
> You can quickly call that whenever you need to save a stroke of genius. –  Dawson B  Jan 30, 2017 at 6:03

Just tested this as I was looking for the same functionality, can confirm it works still on macOS Monterey (12.6) at least.