# Copy the output of the last command in iTerm2

Tags: macos, terminal.app, iterm2

With the default *Terminal.app*, one can select the previous command output with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then copy it with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1158270/63351)).

Is there a similar shortcut for *iTerm2*?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

- [Install Shell Integration](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html): `iTerm2` > `Install Shell Integration`
- Restart iTerm2 (or just source the script)
- Run some command that produces output, e.g. `pwd`
- Verify that `Edit` > `Select Output of Last Command` is enabled, and that the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> works as well.

Note: the solution also works over SSH if you [source the shell integration script](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html)

Comment: @SidaZhou It *does* work when you SSH to a machine, as long as the remote shell also sources the shell integration script.

Comment: Please note that restarting iTerm2 is not necessary, as long as the shell integration script is sourced after installation

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the same for iTerm2 at least in El Capitan.